# How to trace a function based on library::method?

Tags: r, function, methods, stack-trace

I was reviewing the function `install_github` which I thought belonged to the library `devtools`.

It does, sort of.  It belongs to a library `remotes`.

When an error triggers in RStudio, you have a way to trace the stack to troubleshoot.  Can I apply that logic proactively?

Is there a function `traceFunction()` or something that can see return a list of sequential `library::method` calls?

If the function doesn't exist, could it?

```
traceFunction("install_github");
```

To clarify, I did `git clone` on the referenced packages.  `devtools` has the following:

```
#' @importFrom remotes install_github
#' @rdname remote-reexports
#' @export
install_github <- with_pkgbuild_build_tools(with_ellipsis(remotes::install_github))
```

Where `remotes` has the following:

```
#' # To install from a private repo, use auth_token with a token
#' # from https://github.com/settings/tokens. You only need the
#' # repo scope. Best practice is to save your PAT in env var called
#' # GITHUB_PAT.
#' install_github("hadley/private", auth_token = "abc")
#'
#' # To pass option arguments to `R CDM INSTALL` use `INSTALL_opts`. e.g. to
#' install a package with source references and tests
#' install_github("rstudio/shiny", INSTALL_opts = c("--with-keep.source", "--install-tests"))
#' }
install_github <- function(repo,
                           ref = "HEAD",
                           subdir = NULL,
                           auth_token = github_pat(quiet),
                           host = "api.github.com",
                           dependencies = NA,
                           upgrade = c("default", "ask", "always", "never"),
                           force = FALSE,
                           quiet = FALSE,
                           build = TRUE, build_opts = c("--no-resave-data", "--no-manual", "--no-build-vignettes"),
                           build_manual = FALSE, build_vignettes = FALSE,
                           repos = getOption("repos"),
                           type = getOption("pkgType"),
                           ...) {

  remotes <- lapply(repo, github_remote, ref = ref,
    subdir = subdir, auth_token = auth_token, host = host)

  install_remotes(remotes, auth_token = auth_token, host = host,
    dependencies = dependencies,
    upgrade = upgrade,
    force = force,
    quiet = quiet,
    build = build,
    build_opts = build_opts,
    build_manual = build_manual,
    build_vignettes = build_vignettes,
    repos = repos,
    type = type,
    ...)
}
```

which calls `install_remotes` which I don't readily find by searching all ".R" files in the repository `remotes`.

Comment: you could try debug() on that function to step through it, if ithelps

Comment: I don’t fully understand what you’re looking for: do you want a stack trace (i.e. `traceback()`) or do you want to set a breakpoint (`debug()`, as mentioned) or do you want to break on error (`options(error = recover)`)? — For none of these methods does it matter where the function comes from. They work the same for package functions and for functions defined outside packages in your scripts, nor does it matter *which* package they are from.

Comment: I want a `traceforward()` before an error occurs.  Can you tell me all the methods that the function ```devtools::install_github``` calls to successfully execute, and ordered list of items of the form: ```library::method```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no. R is dynamically typed and has a number of different typing systems (S3, S4, R6, etc.). In short, we see the effect of the dynamic typing in calls to e.g. `print` or `plot`. You might have noticed that `print` behaves differently for matrices, simple vectors, lists, data.frames etc. `plot` is even more diverse and can handle the former mentioned types, as well as almost any custom object thrown to it from other packages (correlation matrices, heatmaps, etc.) - and produces widely different results.

This is due to R's method dispatching (and similar ideas for the different typing system), which basically looks at the class of the object passed as the first argument(s) to the function. It then tries to call `plot.<class>` for each class in the class-attribute of the object, until something works. If nothing works, it falls back to `plot.default`.

This is why many packages can use the `plot`-function. They implement a plot-function, say `plot.foobaz` that works for their `foobaz`-classed objects.

Then there are methods that, based on the input, concatenate function names *and then tries to call them*.

On top of that, we can throw different packages into the environment (with e.g. `library`) which might alter the path of execution, when a package's methods *mask* a previously loaded package.

So to proactively figure out the call tree of method, it would be restricted to be based on the *actual objects passed*. There is a package that does this, https://rdrr.io/cran/lobstr/man/cst.html.

Comment: I don’t think this is related to OP’s question. Furthermore, what you’re describing seems to be unrelated to dynamic typing. It’s simply polymorphism, and statically typed languages also possess it.

Comment: My point in the answer is that the chain of called methods cannot be determined from the source code alone, unless you want to expand it into every single possible path given any input.

Comment: Oh, it seems that you interpreted the question fundamentally differently from me (see my comment below the question). But I can see that your interpretation might be the correct one (and in that case your answer is indeed spot-on), so have an upvote.

Comment: I do have the `source code` on my system in the libraries path.  I guess I could write a parser on fn ```devtools::install_github```, identify the functions it calls, and then have a dictionary of fn's and where they live.  Most "libraries" use the ```library::method``` notation for externals, but I would have to have a list of all library functions, not just those exported.  Not hard to transverse the `R` folder of the library.  I was just hoping for an internal that did the tracing.

Comment: It is a challenge to evaluate the quality of a library if you can't fully trace it's roots.  And assess the necessity of independencies.  Difficult to assess if you can trace a function to all of the `library::method` calls it makes.  I thought I needed `devtools::source_url` until I saw what was actually going on.  It was including 4-5 different libraries to call ``base::source`` so I wrote a few basic caching/downloading functions and can do it myself with about 300 lines of code and no external libraries.

Comment: I've got my function ```includeGithubFolder = function(url, ...)  {``` working and I believe the current implementation of ```install_github``` behaves strangely as it unnecessarily downloads all of the contents of all versions of packages, not just the latest.  It's a work-in-progress, but here is an idea of the how: ```https://github.com/MonteShaffer/humanVerse/blob/main/hello-friend.Rmd``` ... I will role it into a package by the end of the semester.  Teaching students the power of the `include` at the moment.

Comment: There are 17,000 CRAN repositories plus how many more on GITHUB (not CRAN).  That is a bit of TMI ... how to assess a package quality effectively, robustly, and objectively?